# WordPress [img] tags

Tags: php, wordpress

Hey guys, I'm trying to allow that standard BB [img] [/img] tags on my WordPress blog. I got this snippet from the net, but it only works on lower case [img] tags. I'd like it to apply to both [img] and [IMG]. As you can tell, I'm totally not a coder.

```
function embed_images($content) {
 $content = preg_replace('/\[img=?\]*(.*?)(\[\/img)?\]/e', '"<img src=\"$1\" alt=\"" . basename("$1") . "\" />"', $content);
 return $content;
}

add_filter('comment_text', 'embed_images');
```

I know '||' is 'or' but don't know enough coding to make the changes. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick solution would be to make the regex case-insensitive: Replace

```
'/\[img=?\]*(.*?)(\[\/img)?\]/e'
```

with

```
'/\[img=?\]*(.*?)(\[\/img)?\]/ei'
```

Comment: Beware that this will also match `ImG` tags.

Comment: This is a perfect solution! This should cover anything from [iMG] [imG], etc. Many thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$content = preg_replace('/\[(img|IMG)=?\]*(.*?)(\[\/(img|IMG))?\]/e', '"<img src=\"$2\" alt=\"" . basename("$2") . "\" />"', $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also check the [Shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) api of wordpress, which takes care of all the regex and lets you implement this kind of thing easily, including tags with parameters and nested tags.